# App icon coming blank after integrating React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

Have integrated react native to an existing iOS app, now app icon is coming blank. Anyone faced this issue? Verified inside the archive of app and app icon images are present inside it.

I am using asset catalog for app icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying lot of solutions provided online what worked for me is moving "Copy Bundle Resources" to last in Build Phases.